# Qt memory usage check

Tags: c++, qt, out-of-memory

I am working on legacy application written in Qt 4.8 (C++). After I've made my changes I performed some stress tests. I am worried about their results. These are my findings:

- Without stress tests RssAnon parameter (I'm working on Linux) increase on time
- With stress tests RssAnon increases more rapidly (between 10:05 and 10:20)

[image: RssAnon statistics (from /proc/*/status)]

I put much effort to avoid dynamic memory use, however I know, that behind the scene Qt use it a lot. I suspect that calling signal/slot mechanism cause this rapid increase. During the tests I pass reference to static object between threads and put it in QAbstractTableModel, based on C-arrays. Of course I call begin/endInsert/RemoveRows on every change.

My question is, is there any more reliable way to check if there is no long term memory problem? I used valgrind, but it doesn't show problems with tested code. Beside that it might not be right tool - everything might be freed on exit, but I want to avoid constant memory increase on runtime. Maybe I should check other parameter from procfs?

Comment: Remember that with Qt's parent / child relationship freeing memory for the child may happen later than you want especially if the parent is an object that does not go away like the MainWindow.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, I know the Qt concept. But as I wrote, memory leak is not only my concern - I want to check if the application after some time will not go down due to lack of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I used **massif** to monitor the memory usage - this is the right tool. I found out that begin/endInsert/RemoveRows methods cause this huge memory consumption in this places:

- QAccessible::queryAccessibleInterace
- QHashData::allocateNode

Regarding the question, the answer is - **Massif** - and to view results **Massif-visualizer**.

To remove this "leak" i had to remove beginInsertRows functions.